# How to center text on mobile with CSS

Tags: html-email, mjml

I am trying to get Media queries working on HTML emails. I've done a lot of testing using IOS phone using Gmail and still haven't found any working solution.

I have been using MJML to try and get it working. Shows it should be working fine but I send the email and the media queries don't work.

https://mjml.io/try-it-live/HkO_hEkqr

I am testing it on an iPhone 5s
Gmail version 6.0.190822

The main goal I want to achieve is to have text

On desktop:

```
Left text                           Right Text
```

on Mobile centre text:

```
                Left text
               Right text
```

Comment: Your code sample work pretty well for me when I render the page with width < 600

Comment: Are you able to extract the source of the SENT email and post here? Would be good to see if there is anything weird going on at send.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail will strip CSS on certain versions (IMAP/POP - see the [mammoth explanation by Rémi Parmentier](https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/trying-to-make-sense-of-gmail-css-support-2019-edition-b7cc132ee226)), and if it contains invalid code or attribute selectors (i.e. your `p[id="mobile"]`).

So, start by changing `p[id="mobile"]` to `p#mobile`, which actually, judging by the HTML, should be `p#mobile-center`.

You can thus cater for most people that way, except some Gmail versions. To cater for everyone, then, you really want the core responsive behaviour by default, without relying on embedded CSS. You can still have some enhancements in the embedded CSS for those that support it.

To achieve responsive behaviour without `@media` queries or embedded CSS, refer to the [hybrid email method](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/a-fluid-hybrid-design-primer/).